# How can I extract/get data between two dates in SAS?

Tags: sas

Can anyone help to find a way to extract all data between two dates (for example 01/10/2007 and 31/03/2008) in SAS please? Date format is DDMMYY10.
I tried the syntax below:

```
Data want; set have; where OrderDate between 01/10/2007 and 31/03/2008; Run;
```

it was giving me an error. 
Thanks

Comment: Date literals in SAS are specified as 'DDMONYY'd or '31Mar2008'd  not in the form of mmddyy.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data want;
set have;
where orderDate between '01OCT2007'd and '31MAR2008'd;
run;
```